# elasticsearch 7.3 geo-shape envelop invalid_shape_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, geojson

I have a field mapping as [geo-shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html).

I want to give the coordinates of northwest and southeast and look up the area within it.

I know there is an [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html). so I copied this.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/example/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "envelope",
                            "coordinates" : [[13.0, 53.0], [14.0, 52.0]]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

here is my curl request.

```
curl -X GET "https://atlas-search.company.com/regions_19090403/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "boundaries": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "envelope",
                            "coordinates" : [[37.54069137885601, 127.0164930082651], [37.472603386664225, 127.03280083907562]]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

but it returns

```
'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_shape_exception",
        "reason" : "invalid_shape_exception: Y values [127.03280083907562 to 127.0164930082651] not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "regions_19090403",
        "node" : "4ySStuelRfuJrcg_BQvy_Q",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"match_all\" : {\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n        \"geo_shape\" : {\n          \"boundaries\" : {\n            \"shape\" : {\n              \"type\" : \"envelope\",\n              \"coordinates\" : [\n                [\n                  37.54069137885601,\n                  127.0164930082651\n                ],\n                [\n                  37.472603386664225,\n                  127.03280083907562\n                ]\n              ]\n            },\n            \"relation\" : \"within\"\n          },\n          \"ignore_unmapped\" : false,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid" : "BFdVr06-TEaSLyaeETsxFQ",
          "index" : "regions_19090403",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "invalid_shape_exception",
            "reason" : "invalid_shape_exception: Y values [127.03280083907562 to 127.0164930082651] not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "invalid_shape_exception",
      "reason" : "invalid_shape_exception: Y values [127.03280083907562 to 127.0164930082651] not in boundary Rect(minX=-180.0,maxX=180.0,minY=-90.0,maxY=90.0)"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

and I cant find about this.
I don't know anything, so I can't retrieve information about this situation. If you know what this situation is, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> For all types, both the inner type and coordinates fields are required.
>
> In GeoJSON and WKT, and therefore Elasticsearch, the correct coordinate order is longitude, latitude (X, Y) within coordinate arrays. This differs from many Geospatial APIs (e.g., Google Maps) that generally use the colloquial latitude, longitude (Y, X). 
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#_envelope

Envelopeedit
Elasticsearch supports an envelope type, which consists of coordinates for upper left and lower right points of the shape to represent a bounding rectangle in the format [[minLon, maxLat], [maxLon, minLat]]

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#_envelope

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/invalid-shape-exception-y-values-127-03280083907562-to-127-0164930082651-not-in-boundary-rect-minx-180-0-maxx-180-0-miny-90-0-maxy-90-0/198612

and also I think it's rude to score a question without answering it. It doesn't help improving the quality of this community.

Here is changed my request.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
            "term":{  
               "isAOI":"true"
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "geo_shape":{  
               "boundaries":{  
                  "shape": {
                    "type": "envelope",
                    "coordinates" : [[126.9243621826172, 37.580228767905275],[127.10941314697267, 37.44406286652748]]
                  },
                 "relation": "within"
               }
            }
         },
         "should":[  
            {  
               "match_all":{  

               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match":1
      }
   },
   "_source":{  
      "excludes":[  
         "polygons",
         "boundaries"
      ]
   },
   "from":0,
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "admin_level":"asc"
      }
   ]
}
```